# Recommened books for learning operation system

Tags: operating-systems

I see other similar question here. I want to become Malware analyst. I have learn to program in Python and C++(not on expert level but fairly good). Before I continue with Assembly language I want to learn about OS. Could any of you recommend book(s) that will give me the concepts I need to know. I will be very grateful if somebody help me.

P.S. I had read the rules and I think this question isn't constructive, but I saw similar questions that aren't put on hold or closed, and I get confused. I want to apologize if this question isn't constructive.

Comment: It's not that it isn't constructive per se, but book recommendations quickly go out of date, and there are many opinions about the "best" which may or may not be true for any given user.  This is why we generally consider book/product recommendations to be off-topic, though that may not have always been true in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably going to be suggested by others, so I'll just throw it out here.

[Andrew S Tanenbaum's "Modern Operating Systems"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136006639)

I personally have never read it, but others say great things. I have read other books by Tanenbaum and they were good.